# Spark structured streaming: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for GroupStateTimeout

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to use mapGroupsWithState in spark structured streaming as defined in https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.GroupState

However I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/GroupStateTimeout
```

Seems like the GroupStateTimeout class definition was not found in the package

I'm using the JAR for spark-sql_2.11_2.2.0 from:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.11/2.2.0

When I open up the JAR, there is no class definition of GroupStateTimeout. I'm not sure if it's something that I'm missing here, because the mapGroupsWithState seem to be a pretty well documented feature. How is a class definition missing in the package?

Answer (score 0):

GroupStateTimeOut is the part of ***spark-catalyst*** module. Please have a look here: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/GroupStateTimeout.java

So you need to add ***spark-catalyst*** dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-catalyst_2.11/2.2.0 in your project. Hope it will solve your problem